# Collapse all head groups when other head group is clicked

Tags: javascript

I've got the following javascript:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      if($('div.trigger').length > 0)
      {
        $('div.trigger').click(function()
        {
          if ($(this).hasClass('open'))
          {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('close');
            $(this).next().slideDown(100);
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            $(this).removeClass('close');
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).next().slideUp(100);
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

For example below I've got 2 groups (have many more groups).
When I click for instance the group "**Producten**" I want to close (collapse) the group "**Algemeen**" and all eventual other groups when they where open.
Tried many things but I'm not that much in to javascript, so if you goeroe's have a little advice or solution...

```
      <div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Algemeen</a></div>
        <div class="cnt">
          <a href="dashboard.php" target="content">Dashboard</a><br>
          <a href="admin_memo.php" target="content">Memo's</a><br>
        </div>
      <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
```

```
      <div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Producten</a></div>
        <div class="cnt">
          <a href="product_home.php" target="content">Product zoeken</a><br>
          <a href="product_new.php" target="content">Product aanmaken</a><br>
          <a href="product_sort.php" target="content">Producten volgorde</a><br>
          <a href="unit_new.php" target="content">Product eenheden</a><br>
          <a href="option_new.php" target="content">Productopties</a><br>
          <a href="option_sort.php" target="content">Productopties volgorde</a><br>
        </div>
      <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler way, using css `transition` and a little jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
    $('div.trigger').not($(this)).next().removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  transition: height .5s;
  height: 0px;
  background: #333;
}

.trigger {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box.open {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='trigger'>trigger</div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='trigger'>trigger</div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='trigger'>trigger</div>
<div class='box'></div>
```